# Index out of bounds, Error position unknown, need help please

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to create code that will return the amount of coins a player has gathered in a map represented by a 2 dimensional array.
In order for the code to be executed it needs instructions from a Console File that is formated as follows:

```
Line 1: Size of the map
Line 2: N = Number of coins
Line 3 to 3 + N: Coin coordinates
Line 4 + N: Player's origin position
Line 5 + N: Number of moves
Line 6 + N: Moves (r for right, l for left, s for stay...)
```

My code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /* Get data from input file */
            var data = new List<String>();
            string line;

            while ((line = Console.ReadLine()) != null) {
                data.Add(line);
            }

            // ADD YOUR CODE HER

            // map and coins initialisation --------------------------------------------
            int mapSize = Convert.ToInt32(data[0]);
            int[,] map = new int[mapSize,mapSize];
            string tmpCoinX = "";
            string tmpCoinY = "";
            int coinX = 0;
            int coinY = 0;
            int coinAmnt = Convert.ToInt32(data[1]);
            int coinsCollected = 0;
            bool passed = false;
            for (int coinline = 2; coinline < 2+coinAmnt; coinline++)
            {
                foreach (char character in data[coinline])
                {
                    if (character == ',') { passed = true; }
                    else {
                        if (passed == true)
                        {
                            tmpCoinY += character.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmpCoinX += character.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                passed = false;
                coinX = Convert.ToInt32(tmpCoinX);
                coinY = Convert.ToInt32(tmpCoinY);
                map[coinY, coinX] = 1;
            }

            // player position initialisation -----------------------------------------
            string Sx = "";
            string Sy = "";
            passed = false;
            foreach(char i in data[3+coinAmnt-1])
            {
                if (i == ',')
                {
                    passed = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (passed == true)
                    {
                        Sy = Sy + i.ToString();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Sx = Sx + i.ToString();
                    }
                }
                
            }
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Sx);
            int y = Convert.ToInt32(Sy);

            // imposible cases prevention --------------------------------------------
            bool imp = false;

            // reads the data list and acts accordingly
            foreach(string i in data)
            {
                if (i == "u")
                {
                    y += 1;
                }
                if (i == "l")
                {
                    x -= 1;
                }
                if (i == "r")
                {
                    x += 1;
                }
                if (i == "d")
                {
                    y -= 1;
                }
                
                if (x >= mapSize || y >= mapSize || x < 0 || y < 0)
                {
                    imp = true;
                    break;
                }

                if (map[y, x] == 1)
                {
                    coinsCollected += 1;
                    map[y, x] = 0;
                }
            }

            if (imp == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("out");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(coinsCollected);
            }
        }
```

and the Console File that I use to execute the code is this one (it doesn't work either, no matter which file I use):

```
4
2
2,1
0,3
0,0
3
u
l
d
```

When the code executes, a runtime error happens: Apparently an unknown index from an unknow for loop has gone out of range of the "map" array...

```
An error occurred:

Unhandled Exception:
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  at SelectionCandidat.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x000f2] in <cd8ee2cfc068460888190546c241d3d1>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
  at SelectionCandidat.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x000f2] in <cd8ee2cfc068460888190546c241d3d1>:0
```

I do not know how to fix this, so please help me. I am new to c# :D

I must add that the program will return "out" if the player ever gets out of the map.

Comment: try running this under the debugger to see where the problem is occurring.

Comment: the debugger doesnt seem to pick anything up, I have to add that I am working on this program online on CodingRoom for a school assignement. So I do not have access to the whole directory and do not know how the execute with the Console File works

Comment: You don't have access to a debugger? Get your debugger, put a breakpoint on the first line and step thru. Learning to debug an off-by-1 error is something you need to do. If you don't have a debugger, use `Debug.WriteLine` or `Console.WriteLine` Liberally to figure out what's going on

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: "an error is pointed out by the compiler" - no, exceptions are *runtime* errors, the compiler has already done its job sucessfully and is not involved here,

Comment: You keep accumulating characters to `tmpCoinX` and `tmpCoinY` and never reset these variable for a new coin line.

Comment: Did you try debugging the same code on the local machine using VS code or Visual studio?

Comment: @KlausGütter You’re right! I never reset their value! That’s probably it. I’ll try that when I can and I’ll come back to you. Also thanks for the correction about the compiler and runtime error thing, I’m new to c# and programming in general :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a user told me, I indeed had forgotten to reset the tmpCoinX and tmpCoinY variables, making the program go through the array at the CoinX and CoinY positions even when they immensely had grown past the array's size.

Problem:

```
for (int coinline = 2; coinline < 2+coinAmnt; coinline++)
            {
                foreach (char character in data[coinline])
                {
                    if (character == ',') { passed = true; }
                    else {
                        if (passed == true)
                        {
                            tmpCoinY += character.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmpCoinX += character.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                passed = false;
                coinX = Convert.ToInt32(tmpCoinX);
                coinY = Convert.ToInt32(tmpCoinY);
                map[coinY, coinX] = 1;
                // tmpCoins variables were not being reset here
            }
```

Fix:

```
for (int coinline = 2; coinline < 2+coinAmnt; coinline++)
            {
                foreach (char character in data[coinline])
                {
                    if (character == ',') { passed = true; }
                    else {
                        if (passed == true)
                        {
                            tmpCoinY += character.ToString();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tmpCoinX += character.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
                passed = false;
                coinX = Convert.ToInt32(tmpCoinX);
                coinY = Convert.ToInt32(tmpCoinY);
                map[coinY, coinX] = 1;
                // tmpCoins vars are now being reset
                tmpCoinX = "";
                tmpCoinY = "";
            }
```

Comment: If you declared and initialized `tmpCoinX` and `tmpCoinY` (and `passed`, `coinX` and `coinY``) inside the `for` loop and before the `foreach` loop then the problem wouldn't exist. In other words, limit them to the smallest _scope_ needed. You could also use a single `tmpCoordinate` variable and change the logic so that when you set `passed = true` you also save the converted value in `coinX`. After the `foreach` save the converted value in `coinY`. And maybe check for two "passings" and report an error, e.g. `2,0,1` is not a legal input for a coordinate pair.